# PHP Equivalent to Perl's URI::URL

Tags: php, url

I'm in the process of rewriting a Perl-based web crawler I wrote nearly 8 years ago in PHP.  I used the quite handy URI::URL module in perl to do things like:

```
$sourceUrl = '/blah.html';
$baseHost = 'http://www.example.com';
my $url = URI::URL->new($sourceUrl, $baseHost);
return $url->abs;
```

returns: 'http://www.example.com/blah.html'

the parse_url function in PHP is quite handy, but is there something more robust?  Specifically something that will give the above functionality?

Comment: The above functionality is given by the "." string-concatenation operator. Maybe that wasn't the best example code to demonstrate what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Zend_Uri](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.uri.html) is what you are looking for?

Comment: definitely promising, but still doesn't appear to be as smart and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
print $baseHost . $sourceURL;
```

Am I missing something? Your way seems needlessly overcomplicated.

Comment: It's really not.   URI objects are a blessing (perl pun intended).   So nice to have it when you want to modify parts after you've constructed like changing the scheme, parameters or even auth.  Simplifying/correcting the url with canonical, etc. Abstraction and encapsulation are always worth the effort.   These are the types of things I miss from Perl now that I am in the very unfortunate world of PHP.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not doing enough 'enterprisey' stuff, but in years of PHP I've yet to come across a situation where the extra lines of code you posted was worth the effort. I'd just create a baseurl() function that gives the scheme, parameters, auth, etc. and concatenate (or use a framework which already does that for me).

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of searching on the PEAR archive, and my first-guess approximation of [URI::URL](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.37/URI/URL.pm) is [Net_URL2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2).  Maybe you want to give that a shot?

Comment: Net_URL2 is nice, although it doesn't seem to handle things properly.  i.e., starting with a not fully qualified URL of 'page.html', I check the $url->hostname to see if it's empty (which it is), then do $url->setHost('www.example.com') and for some reason $url->getUrl() returns 'www.example.compage.html'... it's just not smart enough.  I'm about to the point of taking URI::URL and converting it to PHP. :)

Comment: If you do, that would certainly be a nice contribution to the PHP community!